# page not found on install

Tags: installation

So i wanted to install Drupal on my local mac. I download drupal 7.12 put its content into my htdocs (i'm running MAMP) goto localhost got through all the steps and his save and it took me to "http://localhost/install.php?profile=standard&locale=en" where i get this message

[image]

then if i goto localhost i get this

[image]

I can't seem to figure out what went wrong Could some one point me in the right direction ?

Comment: Can you log in at `localhost/user` ?

Comment: well that page shows up but I can't seem to log in

Comment: Have you checked your MAMP error logs to see exactly what the 500 error is? `An unexpected condition was encountered ...` seems like it's a generic message from your browser, or your server default error page. You should be able to see more information about the error, what line caused it, which file etc in your server log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what your problem is, but it's probably faster to simply try re-installing again from the start than to troubleshoot your installation.  It's hard to estimate how much time it will take to troubleshoot when you don't know what's wrong but you know roughly how long trying to install it again will take.

Although I use MAMP with Drupal myself, if you're a first-time user it might be easier to try [Acquia Dev Desktop](http://www.acquia.com/downloads), which is an "Apache server in a box" like MAMP but already includes the latest version of Drupal and is ready to go as soon as you install it.  Acquia is a company run by the founder of Drupal so you know you're in good hands.

Alternately, although not specifically a Drupal company, [Bitnami](http://bitnami.org/stack/drupal) offers Drupal as an "Apache server in a box" like MAMP as well as as a virtual machine and as a cloud server on Amazon cloud.

There's also [Pantheon](http://getpantheon.com), which is a Drupal platform that will let you register an account and create Drupal sites in the cloud for free (note that Pantheon will, however, charge you if you decide to take your site live on their service).

I listed many options; of them all, Acquia Dev Desktop is the simplest to set up and get running.

Comment: Reinstall was a good so I did just the i reinstalled mamp and drupal all good now

Answer (score -1):

Check the directory name. I had the similar issue, resolved once I changed the directory name from camel case to lower case.